# Irregular polygon in circle

Tags: geometry

I’ve been trying to solve an architectural problem: I have a given circle that I want to impose a polygon with edges with given relations, e.g. a heptagon with 1:1:1:2:2:2:3 edges. How do I calculate the edges length? It is for a temple-like structure in which all seven sides of the building meet in a circle with columns. I’ve been asking this question to every mathematician I met since high school 12 years ago until yesterday the last one suggested trying here.
A better way of formulating the problem would be: **Is there a way to determine whether a convex polygon with given edge relationships fits in a circle, for polygons with more edges than three?**
I’m not a mathematician, but I thought that, given it can be solved for a triangle, there may be a way to break down e.g. a polygon with four edges into two triangles and then solve the problem for both of them at once, with the shared edge putting the two into a relationship with each other.
Please help!

Comment: I doubt that there is an exact formula, but if radius is $r$ and the sides are $x,x,x,2x,2x,2x,3x$ then the equation you need to solve is $3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2r}\right)+3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{2r}\right)+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3x}{2r}\right)=\pi$, for $0<x<\frac{2}{3}r$,which can be done using numerical methods, maybe as simple as [Bisection method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) (as the left side is monotonous).

Comment: And if you'd like, you can try using WolframAlpha or other similar applications/software to solve the equation that StinkingBishop gave above. For example, WolframAlpha finds that the solution for the equation is approximately $x \approx 0.49514$ if we set $r = 1$.

Comment: What does this relations-notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stinking Bishop commented, you need to solve fr $x$

$$3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2r}\right)+3\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{2r}\right)+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3x}{2r}\right)=\pi$$

$$x=2r t \quad \implies \quad 3 \sin ^{-1}(t)+3 \sin ^{-1}(2 t)+\sin ^{-1}(3 t)=\pi$$

The lhs is almost a straight line. Building the corresponding Taylor series
$$\text{lhs}=12 t+9 t^3+\frac{513 t^5}{20}+\frac{6435 t^7}{56}+\frac{41265   t^9}{64}+O\left(t^{11}\right)$$ Using power series reversion
$$t=\frac{\pi}{12}-\frac{\pi^3}{2304}-\frac{\pi^5}{552960}-\frac{677
   \pi^7}{13377208320}-\frac{5819 \pi^9}{3852635996160}+\cdots$$ that is to say
$$t=\color{red}{0.2475}905$$ while the exact solution is $t=0.2475688$.

Using $r=1$, then $x=2t\sim 0.495181$ to be compared to the $x= 0.49514$ reported by @VTand.

**Edit**

If we expand the lhs as a series around $t=\frac 14$ up to $O\left(\left(t-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{11}\right)$ (very ugly formula) and use series reversion, once converted to decimals, the result is
$$t=\color{red}{0.247568771507330958953}561$$ to be compared to the "exact" value
$$t=0.247568771507330958953726$$